# Console onExit events using F#

Tags: .net, f#, console

I would like to have a certain function executed when a console application exits. I have found many solutions but none of them work for me. Why the following code does not display CancelKeyPress etc?

```
printfn "Starting a Test"
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
System.Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun _ -> printfn "CancelKeyPress" )
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit.Add (fun _ -> printfn "ProcessExit" )
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload.Add (fun _ -> printfn "DomainUnload" )
```

I have slightly modified my code and added the try finally statement but without any luck. I run the application and then hit "ctrl + c" or click on "Close button"

```
let write v = System.IO.File.AppendAllText("test.txt", v + "\n")
try
  write "Starting a Test 2"
  System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
  System.Console.CancelKeyPress.Add (fun _ -> write "CancelKeyPress" )
  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit.Add (fun _ -> write "ProcessExit" )
  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload.Add (fun _ -> write "DomainUnload" )
finally
  write "Try Finally"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run your example it prints "ProcessExit", so that one works. The reason why "CancelKeyPress" is not printed is because the application probably terminates before it occurs (And you also need to register the handler before the `ReadLine`). The following will cancel first 10 `Ctrl + C` presses and then exit on the next one:

```
Console.CancelKeyPress.Add(fun arg -> 
  printfn "CancelKeyPress"; arg.Cancel <- true ) 
for i in 0 .. 10 do 
  System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Anyway one straightforward option that should work would be to wrap the whole `main` function inside `try .. finally`. Something like:

```
let main (args) = 
  try
    // run the application
  finally
    // finalization code here
```

**EDIT** When I run your second example, I get a file with:

```
Starting a Test 2
Try Finally
ProcessExit
```

I'm not sure why the `DomainUnloaded` hasn't been printed, but the remaining should work as expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but it does not seem to work. See my first post

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the readLine problem. That is what was wrong in my code. I first called Process.WaitForExit() and only then, I was registering the handlers :)